# $A\oplus B \approx B \oplus A$ module isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Establish the following isomorphisms concerning direct sums of modules
>   over $R$:
>
> a) $A\oplus B \cong B \oplus A$
>
> b) $(A\oplus B)\oplus C \cong A\oplus B \oplus C \cong
>  A\oplus(B\oplus C)$
>
> c) $(X_1\oplus \cdots \oplus X_i)\oplus (X_{i+1}\oplus \cdots \oplus
>  X_n)\cong X_1\oplus \cdots \oplus X_n$

I know that, in order to establish an isomorphism I must show a bijection.

For **a)**, the simples one is $\phi(a,b) = (b,a)$, right? Then I need to show:

$$\phi((a,b)+(a_1,b_1)) = \phi(a+a_1,b+b_1) = (b+b_1,a+a_1) = (b,a) + (b_1,a_1) = \phi((a,b)) + \phi((a_1,b_1))$$

$$\phi(\lambda(a,b)) = \phi(\lambda a, \lambda b) = (\lambda b, \lambda a) = \lambda(b,a) = \lambda \phi(a,b)$$

The bijection follows because $\phi(a,b) = \phi(c,d) \implies (b,a) = (d,c)\implies b = d, a = c \implies (a,b) = (c,d)$

And surjection occurs because given $(b,a) \in \phi(A\oplus B)$ we just take $(a,b)\in A\oplus B$.

**b)**

I'm having problems establishing a bijection here because I already see $(A\oplus B)\oplus C$ as $A\oplus B \oplus C$ naturally. Which bijection should be taken here?

**c)**

This one is too obvious too, which should be the bijection?

$$\phi\left(x_1,\cdots,x_i,x_{i+1},\cdots,x_n\right) = x_1,\cdots,x_i,x_{i+1},\cdots,x_n$$
?

Again, I see this as I see the **b** case

Comment: Indeed these are quite obvious. I think what's wanted is to say (for b for instance) $((a, b),c) \to (a,b,c)$ is an isomorphism between $(A\oplus B)\oplus C$ and $A\oplus B\oplus C$

Comment: For $A\oplus B \cong B\oplus A,$ you could just write down the map that sends $\phi((a,b))=(b,a)$ and show that this satisfies the universal property of a direct sum of $A$ and $B.$ But your proof is certainly sound.

Comment: @Justin what is this 'universal property'?

Comment: Don't worry about it. I thought since you were doing module theory that you had seen the universal property of direct sums. It's not worth the effort if it isn't part of your text/course. You'll bump into it when you get to tensor products or free modules.